# Getting the list of changed files from a commit in JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I am trying to get all the files that are committed, by providing the commit id.

```
RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit(ObjectId.fromString(objId));
FileTreeIterator fileTreeItr = new FileTreeIterator(repository);
Tree tree = new Tree(repository);
IndexDiff indexDiff = new IndexDiff(repository, commit.getId(), fileTreeItr);
System.out.println(indexDiff.getChanged());
System.out.println(indexDiff.getAdded());
```

The above code is not working , can someone figure out what is wrong here or any alternate way to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this [code example](https://github.com/katzchang/ProsciuttoGit/blob/master/junit.extensions.eclipse.prosciutto/src/junit/extensions/eclipse/prosciutto/internal/GitJob.java) could help when using IndexDiff.

```
IResource project = session.getLaunchedProject().getResource();
File gitDir = new File(project.getLocation().toFile().toString() + "/.git");
System.out.println("gitDir:" + gitDir);
Repository repository = new FileRepository(gitDir);

File workTree = repository.getWorkTree();
IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
WorkingTreeIterator fileTreeIterator =
new AdaptableFileTreeIterator(workTree, workspaceRoot);

IndexDiff indexDiff = new IndexDiff(repository, Constants.HEAD, fileTreeIterator);
```

Comment: Not to self: sources at https://github.com/eclipse/egit/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/internal/indexdiff

Comment: I'm testing this exemple, but AdaptableFileTreeIterator does not make part of JGit classes... I see that's a EGit class, but I can not find any dependence definition to add it to my pom... How can I do?

Comment: @jomaora true: Egit class: https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/AdaptableFileTreeIterator.java . So your `pom.xml` needs to reference `<groupId>org.eclipse.egit</groupId>` in its dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have problem with adding the dependence on my pom. I create a question for this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899078/could-not-find-artifact-egit-in-dependecies-of-project. If you can take a look, please, I'd be very grateful :)